# How to pressure college covering-up incompetent professor?

Tags: state-university

I received a grade I deem unsatisfactory for the quality of work I completed, due to lateness penalties. The course instructor was partly responsible; he has *never responded to several of my assignment inquiries*. His non-response added several extra hours to my work, prompting lateness on said assignments - enough to lower the letter grade.

Furthermore, the professor has given *zero* feedback on any of my essay or research project submissions in this course of 'Engineering Ethics', only grades - and has remained 2-3 weeks avg. behind on grading.

I filed a complaint along a grade appeal to the Department Chair, describing said concerns, and proposing a resolution in form of raising the letter-grade (from which I am 0.2% away) - after failing to find a resolution with the professor. The chair denied the appeal. I forwarded the matter to the Dean of Students, who referred to the Vice Provost.

The response from all of them, in a nutshell, was "Policy was followed." None of them made *any* response to the complaint - which was detailed, and comprised majority of my letters. This was hardly a surprise*.

This said, there's zero intent on behalf of the administration to bulge on this matter. The only college official I'm yet to contact is the Provost - who I doubt will respond any different unless I shift gears.

---

That policy was followed in grading is true, but overlooks the fact that my grade suffered directly from the professor's negligence - unsure how to press on this point further (or pursue others). 
 Short of a lawsuit, what approach is advisable to increase the odds of winning the grade raise?

---

***Additional info:*** It's a state university. Professor is a "Faculty Lecturer", untenured.

'* - the institution is ridden with incompetence: professors often lack basic understanding of course material, lab manuals are filled with faulty and ill-grammared instructions, outdated website, and a 'sheep'-like student culture that takes any sh*t from professors (hence the lack of accountability).

Worth noting, I called out the chair directly in my letter to the Dean, accusing "complicity with academic negligence" - and stated, "unless [college] is willing to risk being exposed as a scam institution, it should focus less on doing cover-ups and instead address the problem."

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extortion#United_States

Comment: When did you ask for help in relation to the due dates? Once the professor was late in replying on the first assignment, why didn't you budget more time for the next ones?

Comment: If there's a pattern of incompetence, vote with your feet.

Comment: Does this professor have an engineering license (PE)?  Is he perhaps a member of an engineering society (such as ASME, IEEE)?  These oblige their members to provide proper mentorship and may act where the courts cannot, and the school will not.  At the very least, they would very likely be willing to provide you with the feedback and teaching that your professor neglected, because Engineering Ethics is a rather big deal.

Comment: @BenVoigt He doesn't, according to his curriculum vitae.

Comment: This “question” failed to state a question that can be answered. It seems to me that it is either asking for direct legal advice or otherwise over-broad. I would urge the question asker to ask a more specific question like whether he has a claim of negligence or similar. I have voted to close.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first step is to file a formal complaint against the instructor. When your university-internal avenues have been exhausted, you would then need to hire an attorney to sue the university. There is virtually no chance that you will succeed with a lawsuit. If the university had failed to follow its own procedures, or had egregiously violated your rights, you might win such a suit, but the chances of that having happened are virtually zero.

The essential problem is that there is no specific contractual right for you to receive an particular outcome in a class (based on my knowledge of rules & regs in various universities). For example, you might reasonably want to have written comments on assignments given within a week: but there is no rule guaranteeing that you will ever get written comments. (You need to look at the university rules to see what is an actual rule, as opposed to a "goal" for an academic unit). Since there is no such rule, the chairman has limited authority to penalize the instructor (he might for example decide to not assign that class to Prof. X in the future). The chair would not have the authority to raise your grade under the circumstances. As far as the courts are concerned, the university's judgment and resolution of the matter are final, unless they simply failed to respect your rights (exhibited racial prejudice, refused to follow their own procedures).

In certain contexts, professorial negligence could be legally actionable, but that would only be, for example, if an EE professor physically harmed a student by negligently confusing milliamps and mega-amps. His (non)action is not negligent in the legal sense.

Comment: Surely punishable negligence beyond physical harm exists - say, professor doing literally nothing for the entire course. Less extreme, suppose a professor assigns a large project with a 24-hr deadline - and most of the class fails it. Won't this qualify? --


A student's performance is harmed by professor's negligence - thus, the institution fails to provide the services it's been paid for. Isn't said institution subject to legal penalties for the effective scam - even if not violating its own rules?

Comment: @OverLord A court is basically never going to consider whether a professor's pedagogical decisions are reasonable. You're not paying to get a passing grade, you're paying to take a course. In fact, much of what you're paying for is the school's reputation, which comes in large part from *not* just giving students the grade they want and instead sticking to its standards (as opposed to *actual* scam schools, which will happily give everyone an A).

Comment: There's an argument that the student didn't receive the instruction he paid for (feedback on work *is* an essential component of instruction), in which case he could have has tuition returned / credited toward a future class.  Agreed that the grade assigned is not a matter of law.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon The department might attempt to punish such an extreme case, but even then their options are limited if the professor is tenured. A tenured professor who doesn't show up to teach and just gives everyone A's could result in a multi-year legal battle with the department over revoking his tenure.  And in fact such cases have happened. More likely punishments are largely invisible to the students: promotions/raises delayed/denied, changes in their committee assignments/ranks, being assigned less desirable courses, generally being lower on the department totem pole, etc.

Comment: @BenVoigt Grade assigned may not be matter of law, but professional misconduct is. I pay for a service, and do not receive it - furthermore, my academic record is compromised directly as a result of said misconduct. If none of university's policies are violated as a result, then the university itself may be held liable as complicit with misconduct. -- At least arguably. Are there specific bodies of policy or legislature, or laws/statutes/etc I may refer to to determine whether I can make an argument per above?

Comment: @OverLord The service you paid for does not include a grade you find acceptable. It does not include immediate assistance whenever you ask (since several hours' delay meant the assignment was late, I'm assuming you asked for help at the last minute, and so would anyone else who reads that). It does not include being taught in the way you prefer (if you *need* some accommodations, like because of a disability, that's another story). It does include the school's policies, but they were apparently followed. If other students did well, it suggests people could in fact learn from the class.

Comment: @cpast The service includes the service - which includes responding to assignment inquiries. I sent my letter several days ahead of deadline one instance, and a ~day ahead another - and assignments are accepted up to a week after deadline for reduced credit. The professor _never_ responded. One of these assignments was a research project worth a large amount of credit; his non-responsiveness added several extra hours to my work, delaying my submission. Thus, my grade suffered from his misconduct - and amends are due.

Comment: The issues that you are raising are not without merit, but the fact remains that the law does not yet hold that responding to assignment inquiries in a certain manner is a contractually-guaranteed service stemming from enrolling in a university, especially a state university.

Comment: @OverLord If your complaint is "the instructor didn't teach," that really doesn't depend on your grade. If you weren't taught properly, getting what you paid for would mean *being taught properly*, not getting your grade bumped up.

Comment: @user6726 What _is_, then, 'contractually guaranteed' - or how may I find out? Further, the prof. hasn't responded _at all_ - in whichever manner.

Comment: @cpast It's a part of - the other being non-response; prof. makes the assignment, and is responsible for responding to pertinent inquiries. If he doesn't, it can (and did) harm my academic performance, and he stands professionally liable.

Comment: @OverLord Here's the problem: you're not actually trying to fix the harm you claim to have suffered. You're not trying to get a chance to learn the material better. You're trying to get the university to *say* you learned the material better. That does nothing to solve the actual harm you claim to have suffered; you don't have a right to get good grades on your transcript. It suggests that your only *actual* complaint is a bad grade, not that you were badly taught.

Comment: @OverLord As for whether the professor's actions were reasonable: I assume you meant you emailed him, because snail mail wouldn't even have been delivered within a day. Are professors at your school actually *required* to give prompt responses to email? Did you ever go to office hours to ask for help? Because it's not generically unreasonable for a professor to say "come to office hours if you have problems."

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon, you might want to ask a student advocacy organization, or better, the free law clinic, about what "contract" you have with the university. Probably: the right to attend class, use facilities, be graded, receive a certificate if you complete the requirements.

Comment: @user6726 So, to confirm, to the best of your knowledge - unless responding to student inquiries is contractually obligated, then there is no legal basis to argue mistreatment, scam, or fraud - even if directly incurring harm to academic record _due to_ the said misdeed? i.e., faculty can neglect their duties and compromise student success without any liability.

Comment: Your question is leading and has false presuppositions. I'm saying that the thing you want is not an established duty of the instructor. It could be *made* a duty, via the political process, but that's a matter for the future.

Comment: @cpast "trying to get the university to say you learned better" - rather, to have them reverse the harm to my grade that _they_, the institution, are responsible for. Looking through their policies, I haven't found a single obligation of professors toward students (beyond vague excellence standards) - which, per user6726's suggestion, implies they may be free to sleep through the semester and get a paycheck at the end without consequence. It's an online course, and my incident isn't isolated; I once responded to a week-old forum post making an assignment inquiry.

Comment: @user6726 So basically, "yes." Unsure what I'll pursue, but will keep these points in mind. 'Scam' to describe it is an understatement. -- Thanks for your input.

Comment: @OverLord You're still fundamentally mistaken. *There is no legal harm to your grade.* You do *not* have the right to a good grade. You did not pay for a good grade. If you claim that they taught you poorly, that *still* doesn't mean you have a right to a good grade. Your poor grade was because you submitted your assignments late, which is a valid reason to grade you poorly. Your excuse doesn't claim anything illegal was done -- unresponsive professors are not a legal matter, unless they don't respond because of something discriminatory (e.g. race).

Comment: Selected as answer for the most useful comment chain -- university didn't do dick - owell.

Answer (score 7):

There is precedent in many jurisdictions that courts will not, under any circumstances, get into the merits of the grade you received for your work - they consider that to be the domain of academic assessment, not law.

They will also generally not hear a case (except for injunctive relief) unless and until you have exhausted all administrative appeals under the university's procedures.

As to the merits of the case: it doesn't have any.

The courts will not interfere in the raw mark (which you seem to have no issue with) and it appears that the assignment was submitted late and that the deduction of marks for late submission have been correctly applied so the court has no natural justice issue to deal with here.

Why you chose to submit late is probably irrelevant. Unless the university's procedures specifically identify non-responsiveness of university staff to inquirers to be a legitimate reason for late submission you have no justification for the late submission. It is unlikely that they do - such exceptions are usually limited to family or medical emergencies.

The facts appear to be that you took more time than other students to submit your work and have been penalized accordingly. They, presumably, were laboring under the same difficulties you were yet they managed to submit on time - why should you have the advantage of more time without penalty?

Your complaints about the quality of the education being provided are independent of the mark you received. You are entitled to make them. They are not obliged to do anything about them, in particular, they don't have to respond to you. Poor customer service is not against the law.

Answer (score 0):

> How to pressure college covering-up incompetent professor?

Absent any rules that compel the university to proceed more responsibly, your claim(s) would need to be premised/pleaded on a theory of *implied contract*. This is in line with [a comment](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/36388/how-to-pressure-college-covering-up-incompetent-professor#comment65345_36391) by Ben Voigt (also, his other [suggestion](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/36388/how-to-pressure-college-covering-up-incompetent-professor#comment65347_36388) is a very good idea).

Given the subpar follow-up you have gotten from the university so far, any unused "administrative remedies" --in addition to contacting the Provost-- seem unlikely to prompt a more appropriate approach. However, a prior exhaustion of "administrative remedies" (when available) is a prerequisite for filing a lawsuit.

At least in theory, grades are nothing more than a measure of whether a student is developing the knowledge he will be expected to apply & expand as a professional. But a student's learning is premised on that body of knowledge actually being imparted or fostered. For instance, apropos of receiving zero feedback in class, one meritorious argument is that a student simply does not enroll in school to read (or being reasonably expected to read) the professor's mind. Thus, the major focus of your complaint should be that the university is failing its duty to educate or foster the development of that knowledge.

In the event that you end up suing the university, you will have to overcome the retrograde hurdle of *sovereign immunity*, to which state universities typically cling in court. The historical reason of being of *sovereign immunity* had to do with preventing creditors from exerting pernicious control of the then-nascent and vulnerable nation. Two centuries later, *sovereign immunity* is alleged by state universities whose emphasis on sports and repertoire of non-strategic activities have nothing to do with the nation's cognizable vulnerabilities.

I am not knowledgeable of constitutional law, but you might also want to explore the legal issue of whether the university's pattern of impropriety hinders your *property interests*. In other words, whether the public university's conduct *prevents (or tends to prevent) you from pursuing a specific profession*. Although this might be quite a stretch, it is still worth exploring whether that *property interest* claim is available to students of a university which is legislatively established as an *arm of the state*.

Comment: Thanks for your input -- To clarify, I do not intend on pursuing a lawsuit; _bluffing_ on it, however, is on the table. By 'pressure' and 'short of a lawsuit' I meant precisely that: points I can raise that'll incentivize the administration to favor my case - or, more appropriately, to disincentivize _not favoring_ me. Example: bad publicity. I can stand to pursue media outlets to expose their academic neglect and effective scam, hence harming their reputation. May this work?

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon "*Short of a lawsuit*" is why I premised the 4th paragraph with "*In the event that you end up suing*". You can definitely argue *implied contract* and (since that is a public university) maybe also *protected interest*. As to exposing their neglect, making *truthful* denouncements on public platforms might be more effective than warning the university that you are considering to do so. If you warn the university, it could turn the tables by playing the card "*he is extorting us*". As a defamation plaintiff, my suggestion is that any denouncements you make be *truthful*.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon: It would be unethical to offer to help hide their misconduct in exchange for personal benefit.  If they have acted inappropriately, you should expose that in the media, not threaten to do so to create incentives to treat you differently.

Comment: I second what @BenVoigt just said. Additionally, other students surely are enduring a similar situation and they might as well join or support your denouncements. That reinforcement is likelier to prompt the university to shape up.

Comment: @BenVoigt 'For personal benefit' - rather, for making them right their own wrongs. What's 'unethical' is debting students for decades while refusing to do their jobs; media exposure remains an option, but doesn't rectify the harm to my academic record.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon Are you requiring them to change their ways and right every student they've wronged?  Or just adjust your own record?

Comment: @BenVoigt My own - and if they end up treating others better as a result, it's a development to welcome. 'Fighting for others' is neither my intent nor responsibility. Further, best to stay on-topic - which isn't ethics.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon: Ethics is always the topic.  DId you learn *nothing* from that course?

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon Be aware that threatening legal action you have no intent of pursuing is a) unethical and b) illegal.

Comment: The concept of "sovereign immunity" in fact predates the formation of the US and had nothign to do with a "vulnerable nation". Its origin was simply "you can't sue the king". Its modern justification is that the state controls the courts and will not let them be used against itself except in limited ways to which it has consented in advance.

Comment: @DavidSiegel "*The concept of "sovereign immunity" [...] had nothign to do with a "vulnerable nation"*" Wrong. [*Seminole Tribe of Fla. v. Florida* 517 U.S. 44, 112 (1996)](https://www.leagle.com/decision/1996561517us441559) is very clear on this: "*The point of the Eleventh Amendment, according to Cohens [v. Virginia, 6 Wheat. 264 (1821)], was to bar jurisdiction in suits at common law by Revolutionary War debt creditors*". It's existence *in pre-Revolutionary America is disputed*, *Id. at 103*. The [King's] precedent, a state's consent to be sued, and enacted exceptions are another story.